# List and Unlist behavior not as expected

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

Why does unlist not break up the list into parts that were originally put into the list?

Suppose I have the following:

```
v <- zoo(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c("a","b","c")))
```

Looking at `v` I get:

```
> v
  a b
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c

> str(v)
‘zoo’ series from 1 to 3
  Data: chr [1:3, 1:2] "1" "2" "3" "a" "b" "c"
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "a" "b"
  Index:  int [1:3] 1 2 3
```

**(1) Now I try to stuff that into a list:**

```
l <- list(one=v, two=v)
```

Then I tried to unlist and I would have expected two zoo objects. But instead I get nothing of type `zoo`:

```
> unlist(l)
one1 one2 one3 one4 one5 one6 two1 two2 two3 two4 two5 two6 
 "1"  "2"  "3"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "a"  "b"  "c"

> str(unlist(l))
 Named chr [1:12] "1" "2" "3" "a" "b" "c" "1" "2" "3" "a" "b" "c"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:12] "one1" "one2" "one3" "one4" ...

> typeof(unlist(l))
[1] "character"
> class(unlist(l))
[1] "character"
```

**(2) To try to understand it I tried to put 1 zoo object into a list:**

```
l <- list(one=v)
```

Expecting to get the same output as above when I looked at `v` but surprisingly I got:

```
> unlist(l)
one1 one2 one3 one4 one5 one6 
 "1"  "2"  "3"  "a"  "b"  "c" 

> str(unlist(l))
 Named chr [1:6] "1" "2" "3" "a" "b" "c"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "one1" "one2" "one3" "one4" ...

> typeof(unlist(l))
[1] "character"
> class(unlist(l))
[1] "character"
```

It is probably some subtlety of R that I am not seeing but I don't understand how I am failing to get my original zoo objects back from the list (especially in the case of a 1-element list)....

Comment: the `zoo` object is kind of a matrix with some attributes. So, when you unlist, it loses the `dim` attributes

Comment: Yes, in the case of a multivariate time series (as here) it is a matrix with an `index` attribute and class of `zoo`.

Comment: how do I unlist back to 2 zoo objects?

Comment: `l` is already a list of two zoo objects. you don't need to do anything.

Comment: updated the question to show the other case I was looking at

Comment: what I ultimately have is a function like this: `some.func(x, ...)` and I need to pass the zoo objects individually so the function sees them individually and NOT as a list. I guess maybe a vector? Sorry, I thought this would be a simple question but it just gets deeper....

Comment: What about `lapply(l, some.func)` ?

Comment: I guess I should do: `do.call(some.func, args = l)` but still interested in undestanding why the single element list doesn't return just `v` when you `unlist(l)`